# Enabling vi key bindings in IPython qtconsole

Tags: ipython, readline, qtconsole

I have enabled vi mode in my `~/.inputrc` using the following lines in my mac.

```
set editing-mode vi
```

When I use IPython in terminal, I am getting proper vi key bindings, but when I use IPython in QtConsole using the command `ipython qtconsole` the vi key bindings don't work.

Is there anything else I have to do to get vi key bindings in IPython QtConsole?

Comment: I've used https://github.com/wmvanvliet/vim-ipython for two-way vim-IPython integration.

Comment: @KLDavenport I have heared about it as well. But for my usecase I want to stay inside ipython qtconsole itself.

Comment: Hmmm...I bet https://twitter.com/ogrisel (core contributor to scikit and vim user) knows the answer.

Comment: @KLDavenport Even he doesn't know the answer :( https://twitter.com/ogrisel/status/477344523484692480

Comment: I gave it a go again no luck. Surprised Olivier didn't know. I'm super curious now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt console is not built around readline or anything related to the OS terminal. It's a Qt widget that mimics much of the behavior of terminal IPython and also has several cool features of its own (like inline plots and the ability to render Latex).

It comes with a lot of key bindings (which you can find by going to the menu `Help > Show QtConsole Help`) but unfortunately none of them is customizable.

Comment: I kind of suspected it. Thanks for confirming it.

Comment: Alas, `%guiref` doesn't work anymore: `"UsageError: Line magic function `%guiref` not found."` — Jupyter QtConsole 4.4.2, IPython 7.1.1

Comment: Yeah, that was removed several years ago. I'll update my answer accordingly.